# how to mutiple datamodel?

Tags: swift

i have datamodel

```
struct DataModel: Hashable{
        var image:String
        var name:String
}
var model = [DataModel(image:"1",name:"2"),DataModel(image:"3",name:"4")]
```

i want to Multiply the element 3 time, is there any func can do it?

```
var model = [DataModel(image:"1",name:"2"),DataModel(image:"3",name:"4")，DataModel(image:"1",name:"2"),DataModel(image:"3",name:"4")，DataModel(image:"1",name:"2"),DataModel(image:"3",name:"4")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this approach to `Multiply` your original `model` 3 times:

```
    let model = [DataModel(image:"1",name:"2"),DataModel(image:"3",name:"4")]
    var arr: [DataModel] = Array(repeating: model, count: 3).flatMap{$0}
    print("----> arr: \(arr)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using a simple  **for loop**. You can easily modify inside this for loop according to your further needs.

```
let model = [DataModel(image:"1",name:"2"),DataModel(image:"3",name:"4")]
var newModelArray = [DataModel]()
        
for _ in 1...3 {
      newModelArray.append(model[0])
      newModelArray.append(model[1])
}
```